# How to add replace .cs with dll files in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I converted all my .cs files to dll files but how can i replace my .cs files with dll files in visual studio 2012. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Do i have to refer or something??
please tell the exact process to replace .cs files

Comment: By "converting .cs files" do you mean that you built assemblies out of them?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu I mean compile them as dll files by this process
csc /t:source.cs -> source.dll

Comment: So, if you have ten .cs files containing ten classes, you now have ten .dll files?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu Yeah, now the question is how can I replace them?

Comment: You should build just ONE dll from these ten .cs files. This is called an assembly (That is part 1 of Sajad's answer). Then, you should follow the subsequent parts of his answer.

Comment: Idk know how to make 1 dll from 10 cs files

Answer (score 1):

```
   1) build the project containing the .cs file
    2) get the dll from the bin folder of the project containing the .cs file
    3) add reference the dll file to the main project you need
```

[image]

Comment: But how to reference a dll??

Comment: solution explorer --- context menu --- add reference

Comment: @AbhiKhatri : please check..!! i have edited with the pic..!!

Comment: It's throwing an error!

Comment: Do you honestly think that saying "It's throwing an error!" will help us help you? At least provide the error message you are encountering.

Comment: should be accessible or a com file

Comment: u just show what actually u did..!! is this .cs files in a seperate project ??

Comment: I can't post a photo??
i need 10 more reputation

Comment: u just comment..what u did ?

Comment: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/tGb7MvQ.png) here's the error

Comment: copy the dll file to a folder in a drive in your system..!! and browse for the dll when adding reference..!!

Comment: Okay, I'll try but why i am facing this error and how to make a single dll with these dll files

Comment: still same error buddy :'(

Comment: if all the .cs files are in a single seperate project..it is very easy..!! you just need to build the project..!! you will get the dll file from the bin-debug folder of that project..!! you just add this dll as reference to your other project where you need it..!! it is very simple..!!